# Cannot install Ruby 1.9.3 on a clean Lion Install

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

Trying to install 1.9.3 using RVM.

Getting these errors in my `make.log`

```
compiling readline.c
readline.c:1499:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'username_completion_function'; did you mean 'rl_username_completion_function'?
                                    rl_username_completion_function);
                                    ^
readline.c:69:42: note: expanded from macro 'rl_username_completion_function'
# define rl_username_completion_function username_completion_function
                                         ^
/usr/local/include/readline/readline.h:443:14: note: 'rl_username_completion_function' declared here
extern char *rl_username_completion_function PARAMS((const char *, int));
             ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I faced this issue before in SL. I have Xcode 4.3.2 installed (also installed the command line tools) I have readline 6.2.2 installed.

Added `export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` to my `.bash_login` file.

I also tried `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` but I am getting the same error and I would prefer to avoid doing it due to limited support.

Anyone have a workable procedure?

Edit:

[Link to related open Ruby ticket](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4110738)

Comment: What "limited support" are you talking about? As of [1.9.3-p125](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/02/16/ruby-1-9-3-p125-is-released/) clang is officially supported.

Comment: Oh in that case it's fine, but I'm still getting an identical error when I try to install with clang

Comment: Have you installed readline manually? It does come with OS X, after all.

Comment: I believe so. When I tried to install it through homebrew, I got an error that it was already there.

Comment: Demoted from my answer to a comment: I was able to install 1.9.3-p194 fine on Lion, with no extra anything installed. I didn't use RVM.  But I suspect the problem is that you have a manually-installed version of readline separate from what comes with the OS.

Comment: @MarkReed the only things I installed was rvm and homebrew and Xcode. Does homebrew contain another version of readline?

Comment: @MarkReed and I would really prefer to use rvm in order to manage different ruby dependencies.

Comment: @AndrewLauerBarinov Sure. I was just trying to reproduce the issue to help diagnose and failed to do so. FWIW, I just successfully installed with RVM, as well, so that's not the issue.  Sorry I wasn't more help.

Comment: @MarkReed thanks for your comments, do you have homebrew set up? Are you running Lion 10.7.3?

Comment: I solved the issue, see below, for anyone else who experiences this while trying to set up ruby on lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. RVM wasn't recognizing the readline installed. Funny how readline manages to screw up so many people's installs.

This command points rvm toward the right readline location

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Comment: Ruby was designed with GNU readline in mind. The BSD one doesn't work as well.

Comment: @nnyby are you trying this on Lion or ML?

Comment: @AndrewLauerBarinov Mountain Lion

Comment: Yep this method doesn't work on ML as far as I know. I have not upgraded yet for that reason.