# Installing Ruby 1.9.3 Troubles with Clang

Tags: ruby, rvm, clang, readline, bsd

I am attempting to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OS X Lion, same method as I discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343486/cannot-install-ruby-1-9-3-on-a-clean-lion-install):

Basically it's:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

However, this time Clang throws an error on the `--with-readline-dir` option:

```
Larson:~ andrewjl$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
clang: error: unsupported option '--with-readline'
clang: error: unsupported option '--with-opt-dir=/Users/andrewjl/.rvm/usr'
```

Is this an issue with Clang? Does anybody know how to get around this?

EDIT

After trying Shigeya's answer I get this error:

```
Larson:~ andrewjl$ rvm install 1.9.3-p125 --patch xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840.diff --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-tcl-lib=/usr --with-tk-lib=/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/andrewjl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9505k  100 9505k    0     0  52267      0  0:03:06  0:03:06 --:--:-- 50727
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p125 to /Users/andrewjl/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracted to /Users/andrewjl/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125
Applying patch 'xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840.diff' (located at /Users/andrewjl/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p125/xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840.diff)
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #autoreconf
Error running 'autoreconf', please read /Users/andrewjl/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/autoreconf.log
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring 
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/andrewjl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-readline --with-opt-dir=/Users/andrewjl/.rvm/usr --with-openssl --with-tcl-lib=/usr --with-tk-lib=/usr --with-libyaml --with-gcc=clang ', please read /Users/andrewjl/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Here's the log file error:

```
/usr/local/include/fuse/fuse_compat.h:69:10: fatal error: 'sys/statfs.h' file not found
#include <sys/statfs.h>
         ^
clang: error: unable to execute command: Broken pipe: 13
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal 2 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Please submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include command line arguments and all diagnostic information.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
yes
checking for strip... strip
checking for prefix of external symbols... _
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for if make is GNU make... yes
checking for nroff... /usr/bin/nroff
.ext/include/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/ruby/config.h updated
ruby library version = 1.9.1
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-readline, --with-openssl, --with-tcl-lib, --with-tk-lib, --with-libyaml
In file included from <built-in>:143:
In file included from <command line>:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/fuse/fuse.h:26:
/usr/local/include/fuse/fuse_common.h:32:2: error: #error Please add -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 to your compile flags!
#error Please add -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 to your compile flags!
 ^
In file included from <built-in>:143:
In file included from <command line>:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/fuse/fuse.h:857:
/usr/local/include/fuse/fuse_compat.h:69:10: fatal error: 'sys/statfs.h' file not found
#include <sys/statfs.h>
         ^
clang: error: unable to execute command: Broken pipe: 13
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal 2 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Please submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include command line arguments and all diagnostic information.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-readline, --with-openssl, --with-tcl-lib, --with-tk-lib, --with-libyaml
config.status: creating ruby-1.9.pc
./configure: line 18932: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./configure: line 18932: `      sed 's/{\$([^(){}]*)[^{}]*}//g' ${srcdir}/common.mk'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651670/issue-updating-ruby-on-mac-with-xcode-4-3-1/9651747#9651747) answer.

Even though both ruby-1.9.3-p125 and ruby-1.9.3-p194 some support for clang, installing Ruby with clang is generally not recommended.

(Note: I had to accept edit proposal first, then edit. Thank you very much for contribution.)

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try. Last time I tried it everything seemed to work fine, especially as of 1.9.3-p125, isn't clang is officially supported?

Comment: Ruby team tries hard, but new problems pop up from time to time, it's not production ready with clang, and even in development it can bring to you hard to debug problems.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can go to check out known issues with clang? Didn't notice anything on the ruby mailing thread, but that might due to the volume of messages sent.

Comment: Possibly on ruby-dev (I'm not subscribing it), but @mapis have shown me a issue on Ruby bug tracker: <http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5883>

Comment: @shigeya thanks for your help on this, i installed autoconf and automake, openssl but I'd like to install p194, does the installation direction work if I just swap p194 for p125?